# Number of solutions for a diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given natural integers a,b,c,d such that:
$ab=cd$ and $
a+b+c+d=2019.$

How many solutions exist?

From trial and error with smaller numbers I believe $(a+b)$ and $(c+d)$ divide $2019.$ but I can’t prove it or use it to solve the problem. Any help?

Comment: Is $0$ a natural number?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : ISO 80000-2 says $0 \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: I'm not sure how natural a number $0$ is, given how long it took for people to discover it.  I've seen it included and not included frequently, and as long as people state their definitions, it's not usually a point of contention.  For this particular problem, if we allow $0$, then the only additional solutions we get have $ab=cd=0$, so for each of the $2020$ ways to write 2019 as an ordered sum of $2$ natural numbers, we get 4 solutions, except for $(0,2019)$ and $(2019,0)$, which both yield only two solutions each.  So correcting the difference is easy enough.

Comment: It’s not really a question for debate. What ISO says is irrelevant, too. Either the OP is working in a context where $0$ is a natural number, or OP is working in a context where $0$ is not a natural number. @EricTowers

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : I'm not debating.  There is the standard usage of "$\Bbb{N}$ and nonstandard usage.  It is unsurprising that pre-standardization usage is nonconformant.  Post-standardization nonconformant usage is wrong and should be corrected.

Comment: The same methods in the linked dupe apply here (indeed the method in your accepted answers is already explicitly used there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0$ is not a natural number.

We can write $a=xy$ so that $x\mid c$ and  $y\mid d$. Then $c=mx$ and $d=ny$ for some integers $m,n$.

So we have $b =mn$ and thus $mn+mx+ny+xy = 2019$ so $$(m+y)(n+x) = 2019$$

Since $2019 = 3\cdot 673$ we have $m+y =3$ and $n+x= 673$ (or vice versa). So we have $$2\cdot 2\cdot 672$$ solutions.

Comment: Perhaps you accepted this answer to soon? You can upvote it though.

Comment: In particular, this answer assume $0$ is not a natural number.

Comment: If $0$ is a natural number in the context of this question, then total is $$2((3+1)\cdot (673+1) +(1+1)\cdot (2019+1)).$$

Comment: You should **justify the claim** "we can write...". Lacking such it is magic, not mathematics. Of course it is ok to link to proofs of this (which occur here in many places).

Comment: OK @BillDubuque

Answer (score 0):

All valid permutation of a solution $(a,b,c,d)$  will be taken as a single solution. Among $a,b,c,d$ three of them should have the same parity and the other distinct. The case one even and three odd is discarded by the condition $ab=cd$ so we have to solve the case
$$(a,b,c,d)=(x,4y,2y,2x)\text { with x odd }$$ It follows the equation $$3x+6y=2019$$ A particular solutions is $(x,y)=(3,335)$ then we have as general solution
$$\begin{cases}x=3+2n\\y=335-n\end{cases}$$ Consequently we have
$$(a,b,c,d)=(3+2n,1340-4n,670-2n,6+4n)$$
Of the allowed values of $n$ there are $334$ positive, one null and one negative, which gives $\boxed{336}$ possible solutions (with valid permutations excluded; for example for the largest value of $x=671$ we take $(671,4,1342,2)$ and $(671,4,2,1342)$ as the “same” solution)